# Is it possible to run JConsole from Oracle's Server JRE 10?

Tags: java, jconsole, java-10

The special Server JRE variant provided by Oracle used to include a runnable .jar distribution of the monitoring tool JConsole. As of version 10 (and I believe also since 9 already) this is not contained in the package anymore.

Is it still possible to run the tool via CLI somehow? I noticed that the JDK also does not contain the .jar anymore. However, it is still possible to launch using something like:

```
java --add-modules jdk.jconsole sun.tools.jconsole.JConsole
```

Unfortunately this does not work on the JRE.

Comment: The jdk.jconsole module is linked into the JDK image, not the JRE image. In the JDK image you can use bin/jconsole to launch it as before.

Comment: Yes, I know. I am trying to find a way of launching it from the JRE using some other option.

Comment: Not without running jlink yourself to create a new run-time image that is equivalent to the JRE build and also includes the jdk.jconsole module.